# Export jsp data values to PDF

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, pdf

I need to dynamically export my data values displayed in jsp Page into Pdf format and display to the user on the browser. On the server side I am using Spring mvc framework. So I am not sure this should be handled on the client side using javascript/jquery or some piece of server side code should be used.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: what data values you want to print? **a div?**

Comment: yes, some binding values from db that could be  within in a div or another tag. @ShantaramTupe

Comment: you can refer [this question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17753420/3425489)